# Basic C Shell Implementation: Executing Commands

Tags: c, shell

I'm stuck on a piece of work which requires me to write a basic shell in C to be run on minix, following the pseudo code below (1). This is my first time using C and at the minute its all a little over my head. Ive just about managed to write the first part of the program (prompting user for input, then parsing the input into tokens to break down into commands and arguments). But i am struggling with then executing the command.

I'm not looking for someone to just do the work for me and then give me the answer, what I really need is help to understand what it is that I need to do to complete the task (i.e. a general outline, resources I can use, etc.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*Following suggestions that the question is too broad, I would like to point out that the main thing i'm having trouble with here is understanding the 'execve' function (even after reading the man page)

---

(1)

```
#define TRUE 1
/* declare cmd, params, envp, stat, prompt, readcmd */ 

while (TRUE) { /* repeat forever */ 
    prompt(); /* display prompt */ 
    readcmd(cmd, params); /* read input from terminal*/ 
    if (fork() != 0) { /* fork child process */ 
        /* parent code */ 
        waitpid(-1, &stat, 0); /* wait for child */ 
        } else { 
        /* child code */ 
        execve(cmd, params, envp); /* execute command */ 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Even though you claim you don't want someone to do it for you, the help you request is too broad for a SO question, in my opinion. Or in the best case your question is off-topic because you ask for an external resource or tutorial. [google](http://www.google.com) is your friend my friend.

Comment: What do you mean by "executing the command" ?

Comment: The first moments of your using C should be in the writing of the Hello World program.

Comment: Looks like a surprisingly difficult task for a first-time C coder. How did you end up with this?

Comment: @GergelyBacso First Semester Operating Systems module coursework.

Comment: @iharob To be more specific, the main thing I'm struggling with is understanding the execve command (which i gather is the command i need to use to execute the users command), even after viewing the man pages and other resources

Comment: @PierreRoudaut The basic shell would take a command, something as simple as 'ls' and then execute that.

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp)

Comment: After calling any of the `exec*()` functions, always call `perror()` then `exit()` because when the exec*() fails, the child code does not want to be continuing execution in the parents' code

Comment: the `fork()` function has three kinds of return values 1) >0 means parent 2) =0 means child 3) <0 means child not created, still in parent, with error.  The code needs to address all three conditions.

Comment: stackoverflow.com contains several questions/answers regarding the use of fork() and the exec*() commands.  Suggest searching (google works fine) for such examples and using them as a guide

Comment: there are other variations of the exec*() commands that do not require passing the *envp[] variable as a parameter and the system commands do not need (so ignore) that parameter.

Comment: suggest modifying the readcmd() function so the returned array of pointers to char (the `params` parameter) includes the cmd as the first entry in the array,  then you can use the execvp() function with out having to modify the arrays.  syntax for the execvp() function is: `int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments below your question, if this is the first time you're using C, you should be learning how to write a basic ***Hello World*** program and not how to code a unix shell from scratch !

But since you asked, I'm going to give you some guidelines with the fragment of code you already have :-)

- First of all, it is very bad practice to make blind calls to `fork()` and `execve()` without even checking if your input is a valid unix command.
- You need to check first if the input is a command that can actually be executed. For this, you will have to locate (if it exists) the binary of your input command. For example, the **ls** command is actually a binary located in **/bin/ls**. Luckily for Unix users, a variable named **PATH** and stored in the  environnement will inform the shell where to look for binaries.
- `$> env` will print you all the variables stored in the environnement. By doing this, you will see a line that pretty much looks like this depending on each operating system:

> PATH=/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

This line contains several paths concatenated with a colon "**:**" These paths correspond to the folders where common system binaries are stored.

- So if the command you want to execute exist, it's binary should be located in one of those folder !

  1. As a third argument of your main function, you can retrieve the `char **env` in your C program. Iterate over it until you find the **PATH** line.
  2. Split this line into a list of paths
  3. Iterate over this list and for each path, append your input command at the end. Then, pass it to the very handy `stat()` function that will give you several usefull informations (if the file exists, if it has execution rights...). Reading **man 2 stat** would also help you a lot in this exercise by the way
  4. Over your iteration, if one the created paths exists and has execution rights, save this path and execute it later with `execve()`. Otherwise, if none of the created paths exists (`stat()` returning -1) or doesn't have execution right, the input is probably not a command. You should also learn about builtins http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins
  5. The `$> which <command>` is very usefull to locate existing commands or aliases

That should help you through the process but then again, I would also advise you to do several tutorials on `fork()` and `execve()`.

Best of luck !